Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso issue with request.ToHttpRequestData() after an update
I am in the process of upgrading the following packages from 1.0.0 to 1.0.3
as I see 1.0.0 is deprecated.
Sustainsys.Saml2 and Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc
Once updated, I ran an issue where the following line is complaining:
var commandResult = CommandFactory.GetCommand(CommandFactory.AcsCommandName).Run(request.ToHttpRequestData(), Saml2Controller.Options);

I didn't find any example with the parameters to pass into it. Wondering what should I pass as modulePath?
Any help or suggestions would be really helpful.
Thank you!

I ended up passing empty string for module path. Here's the screenshot:

Note this is only for v 1.0.3
